# How to show grade according to marks in php?

Tags: php

code:

```
<?php
    if($outoff!=0)
    {
        $grade = ($score/$outoff)*100;
        if($grade <= 39)
        {
            echo '<span class="text-danger">Bad</span>';
        }
        else if($grade >=74)
        {
            echo '<span class="text-warning">Average</span>';
        }
        else if($grade >=100)
        {
            echo '<span class="text-success">Good</span>';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //no comment please
    }
?>
```

Show grade according to:-

> 0-39 (Bad)
>
> 40-74 (Average)
>
> 75-100 (Good)

In this question I want to show message `bad, average, good` according to grade. Suppose if `grade` is `0-39` then it will show bad similarly if `grade` is `40-74` then show `average` like this but the condition I am giving is wrong. So, how can I do it?

Comment: `>= 74` should be `<= 74` and `>= 100` should be `<= 100`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make changes to you code as follow:

```
<?php
    if($outoff!=0)
    {
        $grade = ($score/$outoff)*100;
        if( $grade >= 0 && $grade < 40 ) {
            echo '<span class="text-danger">Bad</span>';
        }
        else if( $grade > 39 && $grade < 75 ) {
            echo '<span class="text-warning">Average</span>';
        }
        else if($grade > 74 && $grade <= 100 ) {
            echo '<span class="text-success">Good</span>';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //no comment please
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change greater than to less than.

```
<?php
    if($outoff!=0)
    {
        $grade = ($score/$outoff)*100;
        if($grade <= 39)
        {
            echo '<span class="text-danger">Bad</span>';
        }
        else if($grade <=74)   //Change to less than here.
        {
            echo '<span class="text-warning">Average</span>';
        }
        else if($grade <=100)  //Change to less than here.
        {
            echo '<span class="text-success">Good</span>';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //no comment please
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify the conditions so that no score is missed out of grade.

So, please define 3 ranges of scores using `if` and `else if'.

```
Range 1: 0-39: if ($grade <= 39) {
Range 2: 40-74: else if($grade <=74) {
Range 3: 75-100: else if($grade <=100) {
```

This way, first `if` checks if the grade is less than or equal to `39`.

If yes, grade is `Bad`.

Else, if `score`, does not fit in this range, it will go ahead in next `if else` for the range: `40-74` and same way to `75-100` if it does not fit.

**Corrected code:**

```
if ($outoff!=0) {
    $grade = ($score/$outoff)*100;
    if ($grade <= 39) { // Score range: 0-39
        echo '<span class="text-danger">Bad</span>';
    }
    // If $score is coming to this else if means it is definitely
    // greater than 39: that is 40+
    // Score range: 40-74 as it is in else if after if of `39`
    else if($grade <=74) {
        echo '<span class="text-warning">Average</span>';
    }
    // Score range: 75-100 as it is in else if after 0 - 39 and 40 - 74
    else if($grade <=100) {
        echo '<span class="text-success">Good</span>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if($outoff!=0)
{
    $grade = ($score/$outoff)*100;
    if( $grade > 0 && $grade <= 39 ) {
        echo '<span class="text-danger">Bad</span>';
    }
    else if( $grade >= 40 && $grade <= 74 ) {
        echo '<span class="text-warning">Average</span>';
    }
    else if($grade >= 75 && $grade <= 100 ) {
        echo '<span class="text-success">Good</span>';
    }
}
else
{
//no comment please
}
?>
```